# Magento ver. EE1.13.0.2 tmp table deleted frequently

Tags: magento-1, magento-ee

The following error occurs in exception.log file

> exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or
>   view not found: 1146 Table
>   'catalog_category_product_index_tmp' doesn't exist' in
>   /www/sites/www.test.com/files/html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228

When I am trying to create the table `catalog_category_product_index_tmp` through phpmyadmin after running `php shell/indexer.php reindexall` the table is automatically deleted and through the exception like above.

Advance thanks

Comment: Hi @Jjo, did you ever find a solution to this?  I am encountering the same issue, on Magento 1.14.2.4.